# Counting consecutive cases only they share the same id and are in the consecutive order

Tags: counting

I desperately need your help.

I wan to count the number of night that people have less sleep in a row.

For example, here the data set I have

[image: 1]

The last column shows the number of consecutive nights that a participant has less sleep.
But, if you see the date (C2DDAY) variable, you would find that the days are not in consecutive.
I want to have the value showing the number of consecutive days with sleep loss for this person.
So, the number in the last column should look like this: [1, 1, 2,3,4,5].

Would you please help me have the result I want?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: @Rob I know what you mean, but at least it's clear what the person wants. I'm not going to give away the solution, but I'll give strong hints towards the solution to the 'question' and also help the person be clearer in the future so that the next time the person has a question, he/she is hopefully more included to actually do more research beforehand etc. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So when inserting a new row into the data set, I'm guessing/assuming you have access to the `C2DDAY` of today. If you look at the latest entry in the data set you can compare the `C2DDAY` of today with the `C2DDAY` in the latest entry +1 (`today == dayOfLatestEntry+1`) and if they are equal you know that the person has had one more consecutive day with sleeploss so you can add one to the `consecsleeploss` value of the latest entry and use that as the value to insert. If the previously mentioned C2DDAY comparison isn't equal you know it's not a consecutive day annd so you insert 1 into the `consecsleeploss` column.
That would probably be how I would solve it.

Bear in mind, you haven't really written what you have already tried or what language you're writing this in so it's hard to help you any further.